# Having trouble with Lightbox

Tags: javascript, css

OK i downloaded all the files and put them into a directory on m server call "lightbox" when I try to use it on a page, the image pops up on the bottom of the page, not overlapping modal like. I changed the images sources in the lightbox.js file to include the lightbox/ directory. The images in the css file are still relative to the css document . So I am not sure why it is not working correctly. Here is a link to the page [Clicky](http://www.kranichs.com/K_product_lightbox.php?pid=555)

Does anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!!

**UPDATE** the text page located here:[clicky](http://www.kranichs.com/lightbox/index.html) which is inside the lightbox directory works fine. So I am pretty sure this is happening because I put the files into a folder on my server instead of just on my server, but I would like to keep my files organized so if anyone knows how to make it work from inside a directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty silly but I put in the correct address for the javascript files but I had put in an incorrect address for the CSS file, after correcting that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is some image paths in the js file.  You can modify them there... or better yet  add this before the lightbox.js script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
LightboxOptions = {
    fileLoadingImage: '/lightbox/images/loading.gif',     
    fileBottomNavCloseImage: '/lightbox/images/closelabel.gif'
};
</script>

<script src="js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```